# Facebook Page Plugin gives a FBProvider is not defined error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, uncaught-exception

I am using the Facebook Page [plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) using the Facebook SDK.

I get  FBProvider is not defined when the page loads:

[image]

If I click on Content.js, I get this:

[image]

I have added the SDK code right after the opening Body tag and the Page Plugin code in the footer of the site. The facebook page is showing but this error still shows up.

Here is the code for the SDK setup:
[image]

I have setup a basic APP which is only used by another blog APP which will publish to the Facebook page.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by a Chrome Extension.

Comment: @PradipVaghasiya I think the Plugin I used was the Google PageSpeed plugin which caused this.